# No customers displayed after Migrate to 2.0

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I migrated the Magento 1.9.1.0 to Magento 2.0.  No errors encountered while doing the migration using data migration tool.

After migration when I hit the customers It returns 0 records.  But when I check the customer_entity table it has all customer records.

I noticed that `customer_grid_flat` table is empty and because of that none of the customer is listed from the admin interface.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My Bad :-) After rebuilding the Indexes it started working.  Great.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, you can rebuild the indexes at the command line by running this command from the root of your install:

`php ./bin/magento indexer:reindex`